# Как использовать полученные данные от пользователя в автоматическом поиске/подборе подходящего контента?

Tags: javascript

Разрабатываю веб-сайт для удобства подбора подходящего фильма. Уже сверстал лендинг, в хедере которого есть кнопка, которая при клике перекидывает на опросник, задача которого получить у пользователя информацию для составления списка из самых подходящих вариантов и отобразить его на другой странице. Проблема: я не знаю, как использовать полученные данные от пользователя, чтобы применить их в автоматическом подборе. Похожую схему нашел на сайте https://www.allmovie.com/advanced-search, где, при выборе жанра, даты выхода или других критерий поиска, высвечиваются возможные варианты фильмов.

Закреплю код моего сайта, если захотите изучить вопрос: https://rohanian73.github.io/

Буду крайне признателен любым объяснениям или советам. Спасибо большое за время, уделенное чтению этого сообщения. Всего хорошего!

Comment: Уточните, что именно подразумевается под "как использовать полученные данные от пользователя". У вас не получается собрать данные, или после сбора не знаете как с ними поступать, в плане архитектурного решения?

Comment: Имел ввиду, что после того, как я получил данные от пользователя, не знаю, что с ними делать для осуществления моей задачи.